# Issue updating in MySQL where the count of selected rows is 1

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am having a problem updating a table with a simple update statement.

The data looks like this

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    id   |    contractor_id    |    domain    |    primary_domain     |
_______________________________________________________________________|
|    1    |         50          |    foo.com   |           1           |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    2    |         50          |    foo.net   |           0           |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    3    |         100         |  widget.com  |           0           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What I am trying to do is `update` only contractors that have **1** domain **and** that domain is set to **0**  ...  So in this case it would ignore contractor **50** and set contractor **100**'s `primary_domain` to **1**

This is what I've come up with, but it's failing and I am not sure why -- Can someone explain my short-coming?  How do I achieve the intended result?

```
UPDATE domains_test SET primary_domain = '1'
WHERE(
SELECT primary_domain 
FROM domains_test 
WHERE primary_domain = 0 
HAVING domain = 1);
```

**EDIT**
I have even tried `HAVING count(domain) = 1);`

The response is always

```
You can't specify target table 'domains_test' for update in FROM clause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correctly get the `contractor_id` values related to *just one* `domain` you can use the following query:

```
SELECT contractor_id
FROM domains_test
GROUP BY contractor_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT domain) = 1;
```

**Output:**

```
contractor_id
--------------
100
```

So, the `UPDATE` can be written as:

```
UPDATE domains_test
SET primary_domain = 1
WHERE primary_domain = 0 AND 
      contractor_id IN (SELECT contractor_id
                        FROM (
                            SELECT contractor_id
                            FROM domains_test
                            GROUP BY contractor_id
                            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT domain) = 1) AS t);
```

The nesting in the subquery is necessary due to the error:

> you can't specify target table 'domains_test' for update in FROM clause

This error appears in case `contractor_id` is obtained directly from `domains_test` in the subquery.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/CSAP13143)

Comment: yeah your answer is better than mine.

Comment: I think the `DISTINCT` isn't necessary. I cant imagine the same domain be primary and not primary at same time.

Comment: Perhaps the DISTINCT isn't necessary, however it's not harmful either.   -  On another note, I appreciate your explanation of `This error appears in case contractor_id is obtained directly from domains_test in the subquery`  --  Seeing it is one thing -- **Understanding** it is another ..  Much appreciated!

Comment: @Zak MySQL doesn't like using the table that is to be updated as a source in order to locate the data to be updated. So using this nesting trick we somehow fool MySQL to believe that the table to be updated isn't being used as a source table, although the opposite applies!

Comment: Excellent -- Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is off-colour: You want to update domains where the `COUNT` of a subquery is a certain value; in this case, where a count of `contractors` with only 1 domain and that domain is of `0` value.

you currently do not *count* anything in your SQL. Instead use this:

```
UPDATE domains_test SET primary_domain = 1
WHERE (
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM domains_test
      GROUP BY (contractor_id) 
      ) = 1
AND primary_domain = 0
```

What this does: First it searches for groups of contractors where the contractor_id occurs only once in the count, and then for each on of these it checks the value of `primary_domain`, updating as appropriate when both conditionals are true.

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/FEQ64530)**

```
UPDATE domains_test AS d
LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT contractor_id 
      FROM domains_test
      GROUP BY  contractor_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) as f
   ON d.contractor_id = f.contractor_id
SET d.primary_domain = 1

WHERE  d.primary_domain = 0
  AND  f.contractor_id IS NOT NULL;
```